# Redefinition of enumeration for objC like in java

Tags: objective-c, enums

In java this is possible:

```
enum VisitSetting {
  NOT_VISITED,
  QUERIED_VISITED,
  CONFIRMED_VISITED
}

enum ExcludeSetting {
  NONE,
  QUERIED_VISITED_AND_CONFIRMED_VISITED,
  CONFIRMED_VISITED
}
```

Note that CONFIRMED_VISITED is in VisitSetting as well in ExcludeSetting.

I would like something simulair in objective c but then I get `Redefinition of enumerator 'CONFIRMED_VISITED'`

This is the implementation:

```
#ifndef RouteApp_IGConstants_h
#define RouteApp_IGConstants_h

typedef enum {
    NOT_VISITED = 0,
    QUERIED_VISITED,
    CONFIRMED_VISITED
} VisitSetting;

typedef enum {
    NONE = 0,
    QUERIED_VISITED_AND_CONFIRMED_VISITED,
    CONFIRMED_VISITED
} ExcludeSetting;



#endif
```

How can this be fixed?
I would prefer without renaming CONFIRMED_VISITED.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In C, and therefore in Objective-C, enumerators are in the global namespace.  So you cannot use the same enumerator in two enumerations.  You will have to rename at least one of your `CONFIRMED_VISITED` enumerators in Objective-C.  Typically we use a common prefix for each member of an enumeration, like this:

```
typedef enum {
    VisitSettingNotVisited = 0,
    VisitSettingQueried,
    VisitSettingConfirmed
} VisitSetting;

typedef enum {
    ExcludeSettingNone = 0,
    ExcludeSettingQueriedAndConfirmed,
    ExcludeSettingConfirmed
} ExcludeSetting;
```

**If you are willing to use Objective-C++**, then you can use an [`enum class`](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-nullptr-strongly-typed-enum-class.html).  This is a new C++ feature that has no equivalent in plain C.

```
enum class VisitSetting {
  NOT_VISITED,
  QUERIED_VISITED,
  CONFIRMED_VISITED
};

enum class ExcludeSetting {
  NONE,
  QUERIED_VISITED_AND_CONFIRMED_VISITED,
  CONFIRMED_VISITED
};

// Example usage:
VisitSetting vs = VisitSetting::CONFIRMED_VISITED;
ExcludeSetting es = ExcludeSetting::CONFIRMED_VISITED;
```

This C++11 feature is supported in Xcode 4.6.2.  It may be supported in older versions; I don't know.

Comment: When i apply your solution, xcode force me to put semicolon after enum name i.e. `enum class VisitSetting; ` which makes my enum values nonsense. Do you have any idea why it is happening?

Answer (score 1):

you cant change that :/

what you typically do is to prefix an enum value with the value of the enum (oh and you use camel case for the names)

so

```
typedef enum {
    VisitSettingNot = 0,
    VisitSettingQueried,
    VisitSettingConfirmed
} VisitSetting;

typedef enum {
    ExcludeSettingNone = 0,
    ExcludeSettingQueriedAndConfirmed,
    ExcludeSettingConfirmed
} ExcludeSetting;
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. 
It is C and not an object. 
In C, an enum is not much more than a convenient way to create and fiery minimally relate some integers. 
The name given is the name assigned to an integer in C. 
You can do this, effectively achieving something similar, you could simply assign an enum member to CONFIRM_VISITED giving them the same integer value and allowing you to use it in the same situations.

One thing you will notice is that Cocoa frameworks, tend to prefix the enum member names so they get a pseudo-namespacing and some context clarity. 
Int this style you would have two integers with the same value but named like this...
VisitSettingCONFIRM_VISITED
ExcludeSettingCONFIRM_VISITED

A more common style would be all camel case.

VisitSettingConfirmVisited
ExcludeSettingConfirmVisited

Clearly, if there is enough overlap, it might make sense to merge them into a single enum named appropriately.

Also, don't miss out on the NS_ENUM facility for creating them. Very convenient.